# WebApplicationInitializer isn't detected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

On my small Spring MVC project I can configure dispatcher using web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>myweb.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I would like to remove the config above from web.xml and I try to use this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("Application initialization ...");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("myweb");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        logger.info("Application initialized");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code above won't called and I have no idea why. Could somebody help me what could be the reason?

Environment: JBoss EAP 6.4, spring is in lib folder inside a WAR which is in an EAR

---

It should work this way if I am right:

the **SpringServletContainerInitializer** class in *Spring* implements **ServletContainerInitializer** and has annotation *@HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class)*. In the *META-INF/services* folder in *spring-web.jar* it is declared that this class is a service, should be called. It is a **Servlet 3.0** feature to call this class with classes as parameter which implements **WebApplicationInitializer** interface. The problem is that **SpringServletContainerInitializer** isn't called by the web-container and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error?. You are missing the component scan which is required for the container to search for the beans.

Comment: No, there is no error, onStartup isn't called. The component scan is declared in an other class which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, that configuration and components scan works.

Check my modified post where I wrote down how it should work in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you have error "javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype", if you want to see the error, you have put module org.springframework.spring in jboss

Answer (score 0):

> The SpringServletContainerInitializer class in Spring implements ServletContainerInitializer and has annotation @HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class). In the META-INF/services folder in spring-web.jar it is declared that this class is a service

In my case there was a difference between the `ServletContainerInitializer` classes - javax.servlet vs jakarta.servlet. Tomcat used the former, where my spring-web used the latter. It declares a service implementation for `jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` so nothing was being picked up.

In summary for anyone with a similar problem, check the SPI declarations and ensure you have the correct classes. A simple way to check the jar classes is with `jar -tf <jar-file>`, and check the META-INF/services directory contents in spring-web for which service interface is being declared.

(I realise this question is quite old now, but I came across it searching for a similar issue).